# How to pass LocalDateTime from jsp to controller using java8 api(LocalDateTime)?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, controller, java-8

I need your help. Supossing i have form:form in my JSP, and inside form:form is form:input with date.. as below:

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="personalTask" method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/taskmgr/add">
    (...)
            <div class="input-group">
                    <form:input path="startDate" type="date" id="startDateTimePicker" name="search_message[displayDateFrom]" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" class="input-sm form-control"></form:input>
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"> </span>
                    </div>
            </div>  
    (...)
    </form:form>
```

In controller I have method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addProfileTask(@ModelAttribute("personalTask")PersonalTask task, Principal principal){

            return "taskManager";
    }
```

PersonalTask looks like:

```
    public class PersonalTask{
    (...)
            @Column(name = "START_DATE", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP", nullable = false)
            private LocalDateTime startDate;
    (...)
            public LocalDateTime getStartDate() {
                    return startDate;
            }
            public void setStartDate(LocalDateTime startDate) {
                    this.startDate = startDate;
            }
    (...)
    }
```

The question is... How to pass datetime from JSP and bind with  @ModelAttribute("personalTask")PersonalTask task??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Spring Converters](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert), spring already has a builtin converter [`@DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) for `Date` and `Time` data types, from the documentation, it already supports `java.time.LocalDateTime`

> Supports formatting by style pattern, ISO date time pattern, or custom format pattern string. Can be applied to java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, java.lang.Long, Joda-Time value types; and as of Spring 4 and JDK 8, **to JSR-310 java.time types** too.

Example:

```
public class PersonalTask{
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")  // or any pattern you prefer 
    @Column(name = "START_DATE", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime startDate;
}
```

Comment: When i added this annotation
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")
 private LocalDateTime startDate;  
And I am trying it:
PersonalTask p= new PersonalTask();
  p.setStartDate(LocalDateTime.now());
  System.out.println( p.getStartDate());
it prints:
2017-05-11T01:07:14.902

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @CSource Printing is a different thing, your issue is about parsing a given string user request input to `LocalDateTime` instance, not the opposite

Comment: Ok, I understand, your solution is very helpfull @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) - does not work @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss") - does not work @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") - does not work @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") - works in my case

Answer (score 0):

A new LocalDateTime object can be created using a formatted string:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateInitializer, formatter);
```

Use the date aquired from your JSP form to instantiate a new LocalDateTime object and pass that to your PersonTask object

To Bind the string from the date input to a field in PersonTask and use it to instantiate the LocalDateTime object:

```
public class PersonalTask{
(...)
        private String dateInitializer;

        @Column(name = "START_DATE", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP", nullable = false)
        private LocalDateTime startDate;

        public PersonalTask(){
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            startTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateInitializer, formatter);
        }
(...)
        public LocalDateTime getStartDate() {
                return startDate;
        }
        public void setStartDate(LocalDateTime startDate) {
                this.startDate = startDate;
        }
(...)
}
```

In JSP:

```
<form:input path="dateInitializer" type="date" id="startDateTimePicker" name="search_message[displayDateFrom]" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" class="input-sm form-control"></form:input>
```

Comment: What if I want directly pass whole PersonalTask object, and intercept PersonalTask object in controller? I do not want to divide the data..

Comment: Im not sure thats possible to directly convert the date input to localdatetime but what if you bind the string from the date input to a field in PersonTask and use that to create the localdatetime object

Comment: Static block is executed when the class is loaded and a good place to put initialization of static variables... this solution cannot works. But probably i will use a part of your proposed solution.

Comment: Good point. Perhaps move the static block contents to the constructor?